# Reactjs with typescript error `No overload matches this call` upon importing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Here is my component:

`export class Header extends React.Component<NavLink, NaviState> {}`

when i import in to layout:

```
<div className="tantum-wrapper">
  <Header />
  <main>
  {this.props.children}
  </main>
  <Footer />
</div>
```

getting following error:

```
(alias) class Header
import Header
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: NavLink<unknown> | Readonly<NavLink<unknown>>): Header', gave the following error.
    Property '$$typeof' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<NavLink<unknown>>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: NavLink<unknown>, context: any): Header', gave the following error.
    Property '$$typeof' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly<NavLink<unknown>>'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(358, 18): '$$typeof' is declared here.
index.d.ts(358, 18): '$$typeof' is declared here.
```

how to declare the type here?

Comment: What does Navlink represent? It should be the type of the props accepted by the Header component

https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#class-components

Comment: @HaythemFarhat - I am not clearing getting. in my case i provided `NavLink` as property type here right?